# With the dartz Dart lib, how can you construct an IMap from key-value pairs?

Tags: dart, dartz

I see the factory constructor `factory IMap.fromPairs(FoldableOps<dynamic, Tuple2<K, V>> foldableOps, Order<K> kOrder)`, but how do you use FoldableOps to be able to pass an `Iterable<Tuple2<X,Y>>` into it?

Comment: If there is no dartz documentation currently, then consider instead perhaps this [abstract dartz art installation](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartz/latest/).

Comment: I'd really skip dartz entirely and move over to fpdart, which is actively maintained, and completely documented, both individual methods and some nice overview tutorials.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz fpdart looks really good, though it doesn't yet provide immutable collection impls. Do you know of any other better immutable collection libs? I also tried dartx, but it was missing a lot of collection functions i was used to.

Comment: I just use "Fast Immutable Collections" package.  They don't have all the higher-kinded-type functionality that fpdart gives to most types, but they work fine with most of the List and Map extensions of fpdart, as well as core uses with Option and Either and friends.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the aforementioned [art installation](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartz/latest/dartz/IMap-class.html) (you know, in lieu of official documentation) as well as some [sample code](https://github.com/spebbe/dartz/blob/40b430ed29cf0f3ce3eac560a62fd894d9834904/test/imap_test.dart) in the repo, I believe this is the way to do it:

```dart
iList<Tuple<K, T>> tuples = ...;
IMap<K, T> map = IMap.fromPairs(tuples, Order<K>);
```

Where what you pass for `Order<K>` depends on the key type in the tuples. If it's a native type like `int` or `String`, you can pass `IntOrder` or `StringOrder`. Otherwise, you will need to create an `Order` implementation for that type, e.g.:

```dart
class Foo extends Comparable {
  ...
}
```

```dart
Order<Foo> fooOrder = ComparableOrder<Foo>();
iList<Tuple<Foo, dynamic>> tuples = ...;
iMap<Foo, dynamic> map = iMap.fromPairs(tuples, fooOrder);
```